# IBM MQ Console URL

Tags: ibm-mq

[image][image] https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console/login.html
this url is not working

this is my mq web status

```
 dspmqweb status
MQWB1124I: Server 'mqweb' is running.
URLS:
  https://fa05b45b4238:9443/ibmmq/console/
  https://fa05b45b4238:9443/ibmmq/rest/
```

I have also tried  https://fa05b45b4238:9443/ibmmq/console/login.html

Comment: Could you describe what "not working" means please? Do you see an error message for example? Please update your question with the additional information.

Comment: There are no error messages. I am not able to see the web console.
https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console

Comment: Perhaps show us a screen shot of what you do see then? You're not giving us a lot to go on here.

Comment: @MoragHughson  I have added the screen shots.

Comment: I have tried it with another the docker volume. its working, but I have to do it again when ever its not working.

Comment: Can you ping the address that it says is not working? Can you fully qualify the hostname?

Comment: it gets working when i change the volume in docker

Comment: Perhaps you can write up an answer for future readers. I don't understand enough about Docker to know why the volume name has anything to do with the DNS hostname visibility

Comment: It gets working when i delete the old docker container and delete it's volume, and build the contain again.

Comment: so perhaps there was some error in the original create of the docker container where the hostname wasn't properly configured and couldn't be reached?

Comment: Which version of the container are you using? Is it `icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest` ?

Comment: yeah.. i am using  docker pull icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest

Comment: We are trying to recreate the problem, but haven't been able to. We are starting the container with a shared volume, interacting with the console, stopping the container, restarting it. Is there are additional steps we should be taking? Were you stopping / restarting the container or creating a new one on the old volume?

Comment: on restart nor on stopping it does not work

Comment: Error starting web server: exit status 1
this is the error what i am getting when restarting.

Comment: Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Comment: i am using docker desktop on windows and in docker linux container.

Comment: If you are able could you add any indicative errors from the error log to your question. You will need to open a bash shell ie. `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`. The logs should be on the shared volume, in either `/var/mqm/errors` or `/var/mqm/qmgrs/ <your qmname>/errors`